# Compass sprite, Yeoman, Grunt & image reference don`t combine well together

Tags: compass-sass, gruntjs, yeoman

Yo.

I got a simple spriteSet in my webapp:

```
@import "icons/*.png";
@include all-icons-sprites;
```

Grunt or Compass generating the sprited image without any problems, inside my images folder, that was configured inside my yeoman project (more specifically- YO. The new one)

Now the image been generated well, but the reference to it, inside my css output file, is wrong. He searches in my app folder, something like `domain.com\app\images\`

I googled and saw that `grunt-contrib-compass` provides api for many images urls, like `[httpGeneratedImagesPath][1]`, but these don`t seems to appear inside my Yeoman project, and they crush it down if I place them inside the GruntFile.js.

Anyone encountered this problem before?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [yeoman build the compass bootstrap scss images path always prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847076/yeoman-build-the-compass-bootstrap-scss-images-path-always-prefix/18436891)

Comment: Thank you @escapedcat. But still you know, even though Compass Sprites sucks. It generate code so big and ugly, that its worth only for cases of giant systems. Not for tailored app.

Comment: I tend to only use SVGs and webfonts. I try to avoid images in general. Especially when using x2 images the whole spriting thing isn't working so nice anymore.

Comment: I guess you do not have such a giant project if all your images (bg etc) are webfonts & svgs

Answer (score 1):

link: https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/419

Subject resolved. Here are the modifications that worked for me:

**Gruntfile.js**

```
compass: {
        options: {
            ...
            config: '.compass.rb' //reference for full compass options list
        }
    }
```

**.compass.rb**

```
images_dir = '/app/images'
generated_images_dir =  '/images'
```

Comment: Actually it did not work. Compass lost images references on build. Image was generated but img url in outputted css was wrong. Couldn`t find way to solve this